# Sass within Vue file not compiling

Tags: npm, webpack, sass, vue.js

I get an error when compiling the sass via `npm dev watch` or `npm dev run`.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/mike/code/chatroom/npm-debug.log
```

It's the sass I am writing within the Chat.vue file that's the problem. I am not that experienced with front-end tools like npm so I don't really know what to try. I tried running `npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev` as instructed here (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/363) but it hasn't made a difference.

The actual contents of the file is irrelevant as it happens with almost any style content within the .vue file.

```
<style lang="scss">
    .chat {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #D3E0E9;
        border-radius: 3px;

        &__form {
            border-top: 1px solid #D3E0E9;
            padding: 10px;

            &-input {
                width:
                border: 1px solid #D3E0E9;
                padding: 5px 10px;
                outline: none;
            }

            &-helptext {
                color: #aaa;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

NPM version 3.10.10
Node version 6.9.5

My webpack-dev-server/client/webpack.config.js file is as follows;

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                use: [
                    "pug-loader?self",
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: What about https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/363#issuecomment-297196238 and https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/pre-processors.html ??

Comment: can you post your webpack config file please?

Comment: @TinusWagner done

Answer (score 1):

See https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    loaders: {
      scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader', // <style lang="scss">
      sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax' // <style lang="sass">
    }
  }
}
```

Also include a SCSS rule

```
{
  test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    "style-loader",
    "css-loader",
    "sass-loader"
  ]
}
```

Comment: makes no difference

Comment: Add a new rule for .sass and .scss files with ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] if you do not have it yet.

Comment: How? I don't know the syntax

Comment: Updated. Try adding the SASS/SCSS rule under your rules.

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save-dev sass-loader style-loader css-loader

maybe ,You have not installed  'style-loader' and 'css-loader' yet

Comment: makes no difference